# Spray Authentication doesn't return right HTTP header

Tags: spray

This is my route definition:

```
lazy val route =
      pathPrefix("sec") {
        pathEnd {
          complete("ended!")
        } ~
        //weird enough, if authen fails, it sends 404 instead of authen fails
      authenticate(basicUserAuthenticator) { AuthInfo =>
        pathPrefix("casper" / Segment) { token =>
            post {
                entity(as[JObject]) { company => ctx =>
                  if (token == "123") {
                    complete("this is good comm!")
                  }
                  val response = (secCompanyActor ? jObjectFromCasper(company))
                    .mapTo[CasperOk]
                    .map(result => result)
                    .recover{case _ => "error!"}
                  complete(response)
                }
            } ~
            put {
              complete {
                "successful"
              }
            }
          }
      }
```

I only have two problems (which have been bugging me for almost two days): 1. I implemented the basic authentication, however, it doesn't reject properly. What it does is either return 404 when authentication failed, or return 200 if authentication passed.

Also it seems like when I add this `authenticate` feature, my `entity(as[JObject])` stops working. I get this error:

```
➜  /  http -a username:123 POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/sec/casper/12 hello="this" this="that"
HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Content-Length: 104
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 02 Jul 2014 01:38:15 GMT
Server: some server

Resource representation is only available with these Content-Types:
text/plain; charset=UTF-8
text/plain
```

This is incredibly annoying!

Here is my implementation on Authentication:

```
  def basicUserAuthenticator(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): AuthMagnet[AuthInfo] = {
    def validateUser(userPass: Option[UserPass]): Option[AuthInfo] = {
      val user = userPass.map[Option[User.User]](u => getUser(u.user, u.pass))
      user.get match {
        case Some(u) => Some(AuthInfo(u.name, rejectedOrNot = true))
        case None => Some(AuthInfo(None, rejectedOrNot = false))
      }
    }

    def authenticator(userPass: Option[UserPass]): Future[Option[AuthInfo]] = Future { validateUser(userPass) }

    BasicAuth(authenticator _, realm = "Lab Private API")
  }
```

I'm almost gonna give up and use uri query as authentication, which is kind of cheesy, but it's better than something that doesn't work at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, regarding the POST `entity`, the `ctx =>` is your problem. Have a look at http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.1/spray-routing/advanced-topics/understanding-dsl-structure/. In short, the following are equivalent:

```
val route: Route = complete("yeah")
val route: Route = _.complete("yeah")
val route: Route = { ctx => ctx.complete("yeah") }
```

So if you need the `RequestContext` for anything else in your route, you then need to call `complete` on the `RequestContext` object.

Regarding authentication, the problem with your authenticator is that you're always returning `Some` which Spray interprets as "authentication successful". For the authenticator to work, you need to return `None` if the authentication fails. Something like this:

```
def validateUser(userPass: Option[UserPass]): Option[AuthInfo] = {
  for {
    up <- userPass
    u <- User.getUser(up.user, up.pass)
  } yield AuthInfo(u.name)

  // Desugars to userPass.flatMap(u => User.getUser(u.user, u.pass)).map(u => AuthInfo(u.name))
}
```

Note the use of `flatMap` instead of `map`to get the user (it automatically unwraps the resulting `Option[Option[User]]` to `Option[User]`) and that if anything fails you just get back a `None` which signals to Spray that the authentication did not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found an unsatisfying solution to my question.

First, the inability to extract POST `entity` results from this self reference: `ctx =>`

I had it as:

```
entity(as[JObject]) { company => ctx: RequestContext =>
...
}
```

But no. I can't. This doesn't work for some reason. It blocks the reception of JSON object.

The other problem of responding properly to authentication. The solution I came up is:

```
entity(as[JObject]) { company => ctx: RequestContext =>
  AuthInfo.rejectedOrNot match {
      case true => complete("good job!")
      case false => complete(Unauthorized, "it's unauthorized")
  }
}
```

`Unauthorized` was imported from `import spray.http.StatusCodes._`

I am surprised that I have to send rejections manually and the way to send failure is not through `reject()` but through `complete()`. Maybe I was wrong, but I didn't find a better way.